# Objective-C: accessing instance variables declared as @private

Tags: objective-c, class, private-members

An external **framework** I'm using in my application defines `theClass` whose internal structure is opaque.

Its instance variables are not meant to be accessed directly.

```
@class TheClassPrivateVars;

@interface TheClass : NSObject
{
    @private
    TheClassPrivateVars *_theClassPriv;
}

@end
```

The **framework** public interface is not as complete as it should be and (at my I own risk) I want to read one of the private variables of `myClass`.

Fortunately the **framework** is supplied with complete source code so I have access to the definition of `TheClassPrivateVars`:

```
@interface TheClassPrivateVars : NSObject
{
    int thePrivateInstanceVar; // I want to read this!

    //
    // other properties here...
    //
}

@end
```

I've made a header file with the above code and included it just in the source file where the "abusive access" have to happen.

```
theValue = instanceOfTheClass->_theClassPriv->thePrivateInstanceVar;
```

Unfortunately `_theClassPriv` is declared as `@private`.

Is there any way I can get around it **without modifying the original header file** ?

Comment: Isn't this what accessor methods are for? Or can't you edit the code of the external framework? Maybe you could subclass TheClass, or add it as a property to a class of your own?
Reading a property of myClass shouldn't be too risky, unless you start editing the value at the address which the pointer is pointing to.

Comment: there is no accessor method for that and I don't want to edit the framework code and recompile it.

Comment: @Paolo: "I don't want to edit the framework code and recompile it" You wouldn't need to edit the framework code. You would just have to define a category of the class in *your* code.

Comment: "Its properties are not meant to be accessed directly." A note of terminology: "property" = a getter/setter method pair. Methods cannot be private or public. What you are talking about are *instance variables*, not properties.

Comment: @newacct: edited the terminology, thank you. As for your previous comment it seem I'm not able to access the variable with a category as also user Avt suggested.

Comment: @Paolo: Did you import the header that includes `_theClassPriv`?

Comment: of course. It's the linker that complains. However as [instanceOfTheClass valueForKey:@"_theClassPriv"] let me get the private instance variable I dind't investigate the "category" option much, but I'm sure I did implemented it exactly how it is specified in the Apple documentation for objective-c categories.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
TheClassPrivateVars* private = [instanceOfTheClass valueForKey:@"_theClassPriv"];
```

EDIT: or using key path:

```
theValue = [[instanceOfTheClass valueForKeyPath:"_theClassPriv.thePrivateProperty"] integerValue];
```

Comment: It will not work - there is only instance variable, not property.

Comment: Don't shoot me if I'm wrong, but I think using the dot-notation to access a property only works when the accessor methods have been `@synthesized`, which would make this question obsolete.

Answer (score 5):

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

TheClassPrivateVars *_data;
object_getInstanceVariable(self, "_theClassPriv", (void**)&_data);
```

Couldn't you just do this?

Comment: minor typo -- should be #import <objc/runtime.h>

Answer (score -1):

Would probably be a good idea if it is an Apple framework to tell us what framework and what property you are talking about, for some educated guesses exactly how foolish or not it is to access that private property. After all, private properties can be gone tomorrow. And you won't be able to get your app on the App Store easily.

Comment: the framework is not from Apple (Apple doesn't release source code of its frameworks) and the application is not to be distributed to the public via internet or the app store (its just used inside our company)